# Automatically saving notebook (or other type files in mathematica) files

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, versioning, autosave

I have been facing this problem for sometimes now, a laziness caused in part by the fact that Microsoft Office automatically save files you are working on with versions and automatic recovery.

Many times when I am starting a new notebook in mathematica to do some tests or whatever, I often forget to save what I am doing.

Every now and then, depending on the computer I am using, the computer crashes and all the beautiful work I was doing is lost forever...

Is there a way to get around this other that manically saving my files every five minutes? How about file versioning?

BTW: Using MMA V8

Comment: For some info on version control of Mma notebooks, see [Version control of Mathematica notebooks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2816628/421225).

Answer (score 8):

Regarding autosaving, you may want to check out the `NotebookAutoSave` option, which can be set to True through `Fromat->Option Inspector`. You have to choose "Selected notebook", then go to `Notebook Options -> File Options`, and set `NotebookAutoSave` to True. Then, your notebook will be saved after every evaluation. Whether  or not this is a satisfactory solution, of course depends on the situation.

But my experience is that the most reliable way is to develop a CTRL+S reflex - this one never lets me down and is working quite well.

As for the versioning, it is much easier with packages, for which you can use WorkBench which has integrated support for CVS and support for SVN via Eclipse plugin. For notebooks, I refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816628/version-control-of-mathematica-notebooks/) SO thread. You may also find  [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/48e575c2ce3f28e4) Mathgroup discussion of some interest.

**EDIT**

For M8, for auto-saving purposes you can probably also run

```
RunScheduledTask[NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[]],{300}]
```

But I can not test this code at the moment

**EDIT2**

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6982126#6982126) post in the Toolbag repository - which may also be an alternative for the autosave part of the question (but please see also the discussion in comments on the relative advantages of scheduled tasks vs. `Dynamic`)

Comment: :Thanks. I tried Fromat->Option Inspector.  chose "Selected notebook", then went to Notebook Options -> File Options, and set NotebookAutoSave to True, but MMA does not allow me to save/apply. BTW: is there a reason why typing @ person(i.e leonid): at the begining of a comment gets automatically deleted in comments now?

Comment: @Phil You should change the setting of the drop-down menu to the right of "Show option values" in the Option Inspector from "Selection" to "Selected Notebook". Then, it should allow you to set the option, and apply it. I double-checked in M7 - it works after I close notebook and then reopen it. As to the names in comments - it looks like the system learned to identify when they are redundant - for example when addressed to the author of the answer - and automatically eliminates them now.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have MMA version 8 you could use:

```
saveTask = CreateScheduledTask[FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Save"]], 5*60];
StartScheduledTask[saveTask];
```

to save every 5 minutes (change the term 5*60 for other timings).

To remove the auto-save task use:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[saveTask];
```

To save only a fixed, specific notebook, store its handle in nb (finding it using `Notebooks`, `SelectedNotebook`, `InputNotebook` or `EvaluationNotebook`) and use `FrontEndToken[nb,"Save"]` instead of just `FrontEndToken["Save"]`

Comment: I should learn to read the other answers in full (this is the second time in a day this happens to me). I posted the above after glancing over Leonid's post and missing the end. I deleted it, but I have now undeleted it realizing that the described background tasks are probably sufficiently different to warrant a different post. (also, I did test the code)

Comment: +1 for `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Save"]]`. I was thinking of this one, but could not find it in the docs, and could not recall the syntax.

Comment: @Leonid there isn't an official list of tokens in the documentation AFAIK, but belisarius published one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mathematica package that provides auto-backup functionality. When enabled, the current notebook--call it "blah.nb"--will be backed up to "blah.nb~" after a configurable amount of time has elapsed. I use it constantly and it has saved me from losing work many, many times. It's better than autosaving since it doesn't touch the actual notebook file: if you screw something up or something gets corrupted you don't want to overwrite your main file. :)

It's on GitHub [here](https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-autobackup).

Answer (score 0):

I've got an autosave routine that saves a copy of every open, modified notebook every 5 minutes (or whatever interval you prefer. It leaves your manually-saved copy alone, and saves a "swap file" in a separate directory that can be easily recovered if need be.  The code (to be copied to init.m) is given in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18380/automatic-recovery-after-crash/65852#65852, and copied below:

Motivated by the same concerns, I wrote the following code and added it to my init.m file.  There are two main entries you'll want to change to use this.  The global variable $SwapDirectory is where the swap files are saved (by swap file, I mean it in the VIm sense; an "extra" copy of your notebook, separate from your manually saved copy that periodically saves any new work).  The swap files are organized within the swap directory in a directory structure which "mirrors" their original file locations, and have ".swp" appended to their file names.  The other variable you might want to change is the number of seconds between autosaves, indicated by the "300" (corresponding to 5 minutes) near the bottom of the code below.  At the appropriate times, this code will (automatically in the background) save swap files for ALL open notebooks, unless they are unmodified from their manually-saved versions (this exception makes the code more efficient, and more importantly, prevents the storage of swap files for documentation notebooks, for example).

In its current form, the code does not filter for only the input cells, but hopefully you can use the other answers to make that modification yourself.

Some things to note:
1) the Mathematica Put command seems to have trouble writing to network drives, even when offline access is enabled.  Therefore, it is probably best to choose a SwapDirectory that is on your local machine.

2) Within SwapDirectory, you should create a sub-directory called "Recovery". This is where the AutoSaveSwap routine will make an initial save of any notebooks for which there is NO existing manual save location.

3) Simply evaluate 
    RecoverSwap["filePath"]
where "filePath" is a string representing the filePath of the MANUALLY-SAVED copy of the file (i.e., not the file that was created by AutoSave).  This will then pop up a window containing the most recent auto-saved version of the file.  The manually saved version is NEVER overwritten, unless you explicitly choose to do so.  Once the recovered version pops up, you can save it whereever you like, or discard it at your discretion.

4) You should probably add this code to the KERNEL version of init.m ($UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m) rather than the frontend version... this way, if you quit and restart the kernel, the autosave feature will also restart.  On the other hand, this means that you must evaluate at least one expression after each start or restart to begin auto-saving.  Once this initial evaluation is done, you do NOT need to have evaluated a cell for it to be backed up (unlike the built-in autosave utility).

Hope this helps someone!  Feel free to respond with any questions, suggestions, or requests for improvement you may have.  And, if you find this post useful, upvotes would be most appeciated!  Take care.

```
    $SwapDirectory= "C:\\Users\\pacoj\\Swap Files\\"; 
    SaveSwap[nb_NotebookObject]:=Module[
        {fileName, swapFileName, nbout, nbdir, nbdirout, recoveryDir},
        If[ ! SameQ[Quiet[NotebookFileName[nb]], $Failed],
        (* if the notebook is already saved to the file system *)
            fileName = Last[ FileNameSplit[ NotebookFileName[nb]] ];
            swapFileName = fileName <> ".swp";
            nbdir = Rest[FileNameSplit @ NotebookDirectory[nb]];
            nbdirout= FileNameJoin[ FileNameSplit[$SwapDirectory]~Join~nbdir]<>"\\";
            If[!DirectoryQ[nbdirout], CreateDirectory[nbdirout]];
            nbout = NotebookGet[nb];
            Put[nbout, nbdirout <> swapFileName],
            (* else, if the file has never been saved, save as untitled *)
            recoveryDir= $SwapDirectory <> "Recovery\\\";
            fileName= ("WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation[nb])<>".nb";
            NotebookSave[nb, recoveryDir <> fileName]
        ] 
    ]; 
    RecoverSwap::noswp= "swap file `1` not found in expected location";
    RecoverSwap[nbfilename_String]:=Module[
        {fileName, swapFileName, nbin, nbdir, nbdirout},
        fileName= Last[ FileNameSplit[ nbfilename] ];
        swapFileName= fileName <> ".swp";
        nbdir= Most[ Rest[FileNameSplit @ nbfilename] ];
        nbdirout= FileNameJoin[ FileNameSplit[$SwapDirectory]~Join~nbdir]<>"\\\";
        If[ FileNames[swapFileName, {nbdirout}] == {},
           Message[RecoverSwap::noswp,nbdirout <> swapFileName]; Return[],
           nbin= Get[nbdirout <> swapFileName]; NotebookPut[nbin]
        ] 
    ]; 
    AutoSaveSwaps= CreateScheduledTask[
        SaveSwap /@ Select[Notebooks[], "ModifiedInMemory" /. NotebookInformation[#]&],
        300 
    ] 
    StartScheduledTask[AutoSaveSwaps]
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks.  I will edit my answer to include the relevant information here directly.